# command line extract from SWF?

Tags: command-line, flash

It appears that most SWF files, if not all are actually swf "archives" containing compressed versions of themselves. I have seen that you can extract the file using a few tools

```
$ flasm -x player.swf
Flasm configuration file flasm.ini not found, using default values
player.swf successfully decompressed, 206239 bytes

$ 7z x player.swf

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: player.swf

Extracting  player~.swf

Everything is Ok

Size:       206239
Compressed: 106427
```

However I was hoping to extract from these using something a little more "conventional", e.g. `tar` or `gzip`

Comment: as a side note: I weren't able to do 7z extraction of CWS with 7-zip, x86 Windows (neither command line nor UI manager); FLASM did the trick though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Relevant quote from http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

> The header begins with a three-byte signature of either 0x46, 0x57, 0x53 (“FWS”); or 0x43, 0x57, 0x53 (“CWS”).
>
> - An FWS signature indicates an uncompressed SWF file;
> - CWS indicates that the entire file after the first 8 bytes (that is, after the FileLength field) was compressed by using the ZLIB open standard. 
>     The data format that the ZLIB library uses is described by Request for Comments (RFCs) documents 1950 to 1952. CWS file compression is permitted in SWF 6 or later only.

**Update** In response to the comment, here's a little bash script that is a literal translation of what the above seems to describe:

```
#!/bin/bash
for swf in "$@"
do
    signature=$(dd if="$swf" bs=1 count=3 2> /dev/null)
    case "$signature" in
        FWS)
            echo -e "uncompressed\t$swf"
            ;;
        CWS)
            targetname="$(dirname "$swf")/uncompressed_$(basename "$swf")"
            echo "uncompressing to $targetname"

            dd if="$swf" bs=1 skip=8 2>/dev/null |
                (echo -n 'FWS'; 
                 dd if="$swf" bs=1 skip=3 count=5 2>/dev/null;
                 zlib-flate -uncompress) > "$targetname"
            ;;
        *)
            {
                echo -e "unrecognized\t$swf"
                file "$swf"
            } > /dev/stderr
            ;;
    esac

done
```

Which you'd then run across a set of `*.swf` files (assume you saved it as `uncompress_swf.sh`):

```
uncompress_swf.sh /some/folder/*.swf
```

It will say stuff like

```
uncompressed     /some/folder/a.swf
uncompressed     /some/folder/b.swf
uncompressing to /some/folder/uncompressed_c.swf
```

If something didn't look like a flash file, at all, it will print an error to stderr.

**DISCLAIMER** This is just the way I read the quoted spec. I have just checked that using this script resulted in identical output as when I had used `7z x` on the input swf.

Comment: FYI you can use `openssl zlib -d` instead of `zlib-flate`

Comment: Note that there are also ZWS files with LZMA format compression. You can do something similar to get the compressed data, e.g. dd status=none if=test.swf bs=1 skip=17 | xzcat --format=raw --lzma1=dict=16M -vv |hexdump -C

Comment: @GreenReaper that's cool information. That looks complicated, and probably took some effort. It might not be a bad idea to add an answer of your own.